# Consuming JAX-RPC with JAX-WS

Tags: jax-ws, jax-rpc

Will I be able to consumie JAX-RPC web service using a JAX-WS client ? What are the effects of consuming a JAX-RPC web service using a JAX-WS client? Are there any advantages and disadvantages?

Answer (score 0):

The main difference is

> `JAX-WS` document style web services can be validated against predefined schema

but `JAX-RPC` is not.
Default SOAPBinding style is Document type. If you want to switch to RCP just change in annotation as follow.

```
@SOAPBinding(style = Style.RPC)
```

More details [difference-between-rpc-and-document](https://www.javatpoint.com/difference-between-rpc-and-document)

Comment: I already had a traditional JAX-RPC web service in one system, but i wan't to consume it with JAX-WS client in another system. Is this possible?. If yes, How can i achieve this?

Comment: @SannyPathak you better post new question. I have no idea how to do it, maybe someone can help you. (This is my first step of JAX-WS) Cheer!